# Middleman Output Path

Tags: ruby, middleman

EDIT for clarity:

I'm wondering if it is possible to have set an output path for files in a Middleman build. For organizational purposes I want to group a type of page into a folder to keep it out of the main source directory. However on build/server I would like it to render to a different path:

```
/source
    index.html
    /landingpages
        landingpage1.html
        landingpage2.html
```

I have `:directory_indexes` enabled in my config file would like to be able to have the files in `landingpage` output to the root directory:

```
/build
    index.html
    /landingpage1
        index.html
    /landingpage2
        index.html
```

Is this possible to achieve this somehow using the config.rb file and still show up properly in the sitemap? I would prefer to not have to do this using .htaccess

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A technique I used in a current project is based around proxies and should also solve your case:

```
landingpage_templates = Dir['source/landingpages/*.html']

landingpage_templates.map! do |tpl_name|
  tpl_name = File.basename(tpl_name).gsub(/.html$/, '')
  proxy "/#{tpl_name}/index.html", "/landingpages/#{tpl_name}.html", :ignore => true
end
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just took of the :ignore part because I wanted them indexed. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have this documented somewhere e.g. here on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like that:

```
page "/file1/index.html",  :proxy => "/somefolder/file1.html"
page "/file2/index.html",  :proxy => "/somefolder/file2.html"
```

I think you're better off [using directory indexes](http://middlemanapp.com/pretty-urls/) instead though and organising your files like:

```
/source
    index.html
    file1.html
    file2.html
```

In your `config.rb`

```
activate :directory_indexes
```

Comment: This didn't work for single files, and I need to have entire directories redirected.

Comment: You need to give more information about what you're trying to achieve. Can you give more background to you problem?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I think you're using the wrong tool for the job.